# If statement in x-kendo-template template not functioning

Tags: conditional-statements, kendo-mobile

I am building a Kendo mobile application. In the detail view I am populating the template perfectly, my problem comes in when an array in my data source **(only for that active view)** doesn't exist - so I need a conditional statement to wrap of my variables. I.E if I'm viewing an item that doesn't contain the array of eventGenre - the view doesn't break.

Any help will be super appreciated.

Here is my template

```
    <script id="detailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h1>#:eventInfo.eventName#</h1>
    <h3>
        R#:eventInfo.covercharge#
        @ #:eventInfo.venueName# / 
    </h3>
    #for (var i=0,leg=eventGenre.length; i<leg; i++){#
# if( eventGenre[i]==null) {#<span>show xxx<span># } else {#<h3>${eventGenre[i] }</h3>#} #
    # } #

    // Also tried this way but nothing seems to work.
    # if (eventGenre == '' || eventGenre == null){ #
    # } else { #
        <h3>#:eventGenre# }</h3>
    # } #

    </script>
```

Comment: show me how you pass data to the template , dont think "eventGenre.length" will work.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone having the same weirdo problem as me I solved it by adding data. to the beginning of the statement.

```
# if (data.eventGenre){ #
  <h3>#:eventGenre# }</h3>
# } #
```

Comment: Sorry I saw this post too late to answer. In the future, you can include "normal" JS in the templates too, so you could have added: `#debugger;#` to stop at a breakpoint, or `#console.log(eventGenre)#` to see what the value of that variable was when the template was executed.